# Remove Duplicate Value using Autocomplete component

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, appexchange, automation

Apex Class :

```
public class AutoCompleteV2_Con {

    public String labelFieldVar{ get; set; }
    public String valueFieldVar{ get; set; }
    public String sObjVal{get;set;}
    public Integer randomJsIden{get;set;}
    public Object cacheField{get;private set;} 

    private Object targetFieldVar;

    public AutoCompleteV2_Con(){
        randomJsIden = getRandomNumber(1000000);
    }

   /*
    *Random number generator to change the js function name if multiple components us
    ***/
    private Integer getRandomNumber(Integer size){
        Double d = Math.random() * size;
        return d.intValue();
    }

    /*
    *This method queries data according to the passed parameters
    ***/
    @RemoteAction
    public static List<AutoCompleteData> getData(String sObjVal,String labelFieldVar,String valueFieldVar,String param){

        List<AutoCompleteData> AutoCompleteDatas = new List<AutoCompleteData>();
        param = String.escapeSingleQuotes(param);
        for( Sobject sObj : Database.query('SELECT '+labelFieldVar+' FROM '+sObjVal+' WHERE '+labelFieldVar+' LIKE \'%'+param+'%\'')){
            AutoCompleteDatas.add(new AutoCompleteData(sObj.get(valueFieldVar),sObj.get(labelFieldVar)));

        }

        return AutoCompleteDatas;

    }

    public class AutoCompleteData{
        public String id;
        public String text;

        public AutoCompleteData(Object id, Object text){
            this.id = String.valueOf(id);
            this.text = String.valueOf(text);
        }
    }


}
```

Visualforce Component :

```
<apex:component controller="AutoCompleteV2_Con" selfClosing="true">
    <apex:attribute name="SObject" description="SOQL Object to query"
        type="String" assignTo="{!sObjVal}" required="true" />
    <apex:attribute name="labelField"
        description="API Name of Field to display for label" type="String"
        required="true" assignTo="{!labelFieldVar}"/>
    <apex:attribute name="valueField"
        description="API Name of Field to display for value that is passed to the targetField"
        type="String" required="true" assignTo="{!valueFieldVar}"/>
    <apex:attribute name="targetField"
        description="Field of current object that will hold the selection."
        type="Object" assignTo="{!targetFieldVar}"/>
    <apex:attribute name="inputFieldId"
        description="Id of the field where the value will copied[Not generally required, used when you need to copy value to a field using js]"
        type="String" />
     <apex:attribute name="importJquery"
        description="Assign false if you dont want to jquery files"
        type="Boolean" default="true" />
    <apex:attribute name="syncManualEntry"
        description="Allow manual entry of data from autocomplete component."
        type="Boolean" default="true" />
    <apex:attribute name="allowClear" description="Set true to give user a option to clear existing value" type="Boolean" default="true"/>

    <apex:attribute name="Style" description="style for the input component" type="String"/>
    <!--Required js files-->
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!importJquery}">
        <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.select2, 'select2-3.4.2/select2.js')}"/>
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.select2, 'select2-3.4.2/select2.css')}"/>
    <script>
        var v2{!randomJsIden}

        var prevVal{!randomJsIden};
        function autocompleteV2{!randomJsIden}(){
             var v2=this;
             jQuery(function($){ //on document.ready
                    v2.init($)
             });
        }

        autocompleteV2{!randomJsIden}.prototype={
            init : function($){

                       var $elem = $( ".auto{!randomJsIden}" ).select2({
                           minimumInputLength: 1,
                           placeholder: "No value selected",
                           allowClear : {!allowClear},
                           query: function (query) {
                               queryData{!randomJsIden}(query);

                           },
                           createSearchChoice:function(term, data) {
                                if({!syncManualEntry} == true){
                                    return {id:term, text:term};
                                }
                            }
                       });

                       $elem.on("select2-selecting", function(e) {

                           $('.hiddenField{!randomJsIden}').val(e.val);
                       });

                       $elem.on("select2-removed", function(e) {
                           $('.hiddenField{!randomJsIden}').val('');
                       });



                       if('{!cacheField}' !=''){
                           $elem.select2("data", {id: "{!targetFieldVar}", text: "{!cacheField}"})  
                       }  

                    },

            triggerSearch :function(val){

                                if(prevVal{!randomJsIden} != val){
                                    $=jQuery;
                                    prevVal{!randomJsIden} = val;
                                    var select = $('input.auto{!randomJsIden}');          
                                    var search = $('.select2-input')
                                    select.select2('open');
                                    search.val(val);

                                    search.trigger("input");
                                }
                            }
        }





         /*
        *This method queries data according to the passed parameter
        *and populates the combobox accordingly
        ***/    
        function queryData{!randomJsIden}(query){

           Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                     '{!$RemoteAction.AutoCompleteV2_Con.getData}','{!sObjVal}','{!labelFieldVar}','{!valueFieldVar}',query.term,
                     function(result, event){

                         //if success
                         if(event.status){ 
                             var data = {results: []}
                             data.results = result;                            
                             query.callback( data);                           
                         }
                         else{
                              alert('Invalid Field/Object API Name : '+event.message);
                         }

                     }, 
                      {escape: true}
                );
            }  


    </script>

    <apex:inputText style="{!Style}" styleClass="auto{!randomJsIden}" value="{!cacheField}" />

    <apex:outputPanel id="hiddenPanel">
        <apex:inputText value="{!targetField}" id="hiddenField"
            styleClass="hiddenField{!randomJsIden}" style="display:none"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <script>v2{!randomJsIden} = new autocompleteV2{!randomJsIden}({});</script>
</apex:component>
```

Error coming from point :

```
for( Sobject sObj : Database.query('SELECT '+labelFieldVar+' FROM '+sObjVal+' WHERE '+labelFieldVar+' LIKE \'%'+param+'%\'')){
            AutoCompleteDatas.add(new AutoCompleteData(sObj.get(valueFieldVar),sObj.get(labelFieldVar)));

        }

        return AutoCompleteDatas;
```

Input :

```
<c:AutoCompleteV2 allowClear="true" importJquery="true" labelField="client_p_n__c" SObject="Quote_Line_Item__c" valuefield="client_p_n__c" targetField="{!inputText10}" style="width:200px"/>
```

This is a Autocomponent v2 free app (http://blogforce9.blogspot.in/2013/10/auto-complete-visualforce-component-v2.html).I tried many possible ways to restrict autocompletedatas from restrict the duplicates .again and again i am getting same working since no luck till now.then i tried with jquery to restrict data from visual force component side .it is very badly acting when i work with component side .then i came back to work with controller side .

Problem is ,when i search on my autocomplete input text like "Ales" it is showing multiple times, since this field value is recorded in many records . I want to show that value only once in autocompletion even though it has recorded in many records.

Let me know if i am unclear with my question .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surprised you found an app with so many security vulnerabilities. You have several injection issues. First thing you should do is rewrite the method to eliminate these. I would take advantage of strong types in my approach:

```
public List<AutoCompleteData> getData
    (SObjectType sObjectType, SObjectField labelField,
    SObjectField valueField, String fuzzyValue)
{
    List<AutoCompleteData> data = new List<AutoCompleteData>();
    fuzzyValue = '%' + fuzzyValue + '%';
    String fields = String.join(', ' new List<String>
    {
        String.valueOf(labelField), String.valueOf(valueField)
    });
    for (SObject record : Database.query(
        'SELECT ' + field + ' FROM ' + sObjectType +
        ' WHERE ' + labelField + ' LIKE : fuzzyValue'
    )) data.add(new AutoCompleteData(
        (String)record.get(valueField), (String)record.get(labelField)
    );
}
```

Since you're not even querying for the `valueFieldVar`, you must be using `Id`. It is unclear how you want to handle collisions, but if you actually just want to use the value and not the `Id`, it is pretty straightforward. Just use a set.

```
Set<String> values = new Set<String>();
for (SObject record : Database.query(/*query*/)) values.add((String)record.get(field));
List<AutoCompleteData> data = new List<AutoCompleteData>();
for (String value : values) data.add(new AutoCompleteData(value, value));
```